# Regex for hashtags at the very begining not works in C# but works in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

guys!

I writed this kind of regex I need

```
^((#\w+\b(\s?|#))+)
```

and it works fine... But only [here](https://regex101.com/r/OM6EfK/1) (in Javascript mode).
 [image]

As you can see, it highlights all lines till the text with no sign of hashtags begins (I only need get them from very beginning of the text).

If I'll try something like this at http://regexstorm.net/tester it would look like this (so part I need not fully captured, ECMAScript option not helps as well)
[image]

Whats the best way to fix it for C#? And why it doesnt work like that (because at other options in regex101 everything looks good)?

Comment: @ClasG: No, `\s*`. RegexStorm default line break style is CRLF, while regex101 is using LF. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%28%23%5cw%2b%5cb%28%5cs*%7c%23%29%29%2b%29&i=%23abc%23efg+%23hij%0d%0a%23klm%0d%0a%23no+%23pq%0d%0a%0d%0aSometext+%0d%0aaddsagdsagdsa%0d%0asadgdsagdsagdsa%0d%0a%0d%0aasdgsadg%0d%0a%0d%0a%23dsafsadas%0d%0a)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hi there! oh, damn, I tought I tried that one, but actually I'm not

Comment: Add `Multiline` option in RegexStorm

Comment: @FedericoDipuma multiline is not an option here, because of I need to stick to the very beginning

Comment: @FedericoDipuma: It depends what OP wants. If the same behavior as at regex101, that is not the correct fix. Danil, your regex needs more fixing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, I will wait for your answer, Wiktor

Comment: Shouldn't it be [`^#\w+(?:\s*#\w+)*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%23%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs*%23%5cw%2b%29*&i=%23abc%23efg+%23hij%0d%0a%23klm%0d%0a%23no+%23pq%0d%0a%0d%0aSometext+%0d%0aaddsagdsagdsa%0d%0asadgdsagdsagdsa%0d%0a%0d%0aasdgsadg%0d%0a%0d%0a%23dsafsadas%0d%0a)? A hashtag, followed with 0+ sequences of 0+ whitespaces and hashtag?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well, if it works fine, then let it be like that (and I always forgot about those LF/CRLF stuff, omg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the difference of line break style between Regex101 and RegexStorm sites: the first one uses LF and the latter uses CRLF styles. So, the `\s?` only matching 1 or 0 whitespaces fails to find a match at RegexStorm since there are two whitespaces between the end of the first and the beginning of the second line.

You might fix it changing `\s?` with `\s*` (or at least `\s{0,2}` to match 0 to 2 whitespaces).

However, your regex needs improving since it is causing too much overhead for the regex engine. You may write it linearly as

```
^#\w+(?:\s*#\w+)*
```

See the [RegexStorm regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%23%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%23%5Cw%2B%29*&i=%23abc%23efg%20%23hij%0D%0A%23klm%0D%0A%23no%20%23pq%0D%0A%0D%0ASometext%20%0D%0Aaddsagdsagdsa%0D%0Asadgdsagdsagdsa%0D%0A%0D%0Aasdgsadg%0D%0A%0D%0A%23dsafsadas%0D%0A). It matches a hashtag, followed with 0+ sequences of 0+ whitespaces and a hashtag.

Note that `^` may be redefined to match the start of a *line*. To avoid that, in .NET, you may use `\A` anchor that always matches the start of the string.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` (or `\A`) - start of the string
- `#\w+` - a `#` followed with 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s*#\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `#\w+` - a hashtag pattern.

Comment: oh, this regex is much better

Comment: It is also ~67% faster than the previous one. Benchmark performed at http://regexhero.net/tester.